# HP: BootDevice not found (3F0), but boots "From File"...?

Tags: hard-drive, boot, bios, grub, debian-stretch

This is an HP7265NGW. I've removed an M2 disk and put an old SATA1/WD-500Gb (debian 9 64bits) that was previously working fine on this machine.

1. Now, the SATA1 can't boot (either UEFI or Legacy), the BIOS error is the HP classical

   ```
   Boot Device Not Found
   Please install an operating system on your hard disk.
   Hard Disk (3F0)
   F2 System Diagnostics
   For more information, please visit : www.hp.com/go/techcenter/startup
   ```
2. The SATA1 disk boots perfectly on other machines.
3. ALL the HP Bios diagnostics state that the disk is in perfect state.
4. Debian Rescue is capable of mounting the filesystem, no errors, and making a grub reinstall, no errors. But after restarting, **3f0**!
5. BIOS was updated to today's last version. No effect.
6. Tried Legacy/UEFI. No effect. UEFI boots a black screen, sometimes.
7. I've run grub-install from the rescue disk, in another machine, after booting with EFI file (see below). No effect. Still **3f0**.

**Minutes ago, I've just discovered the HP BIOS option "Boot From File", where the disk is identified, some "EFI" directory, and some ".efi" file... boots fine!**

How can I fix this, or at least make "Boot From File" my default? pressing F9 and searching for the EFI file every day will be annoying!

Comment: I ran into the same problem (HP ZBook G3) after some sort of firmware reset (I guess), holding down power button for one minute, trying to fix a problem with keyboard failure. Thank you so much for pointing out the possibility to select the EFI debian file. Did you solve this problem?

Comment: Reinstall grub (or re-register it on the UEFI NVRAM with `efibootmgr` or so)

Comment: @TomYan any pointers on how to do this correctly on Debian stable (how to correctly reinstall Grub or run efibootmgr)?

Comment: Not really familiar with Debian. With upstream grub it's something like `grub-install --efi-directory $path_to_esp_mountpoint`. (Make sure `/boot` is properly mounted.) Use e.g. `findmnt` to check the exact mountpoint. (Often the only `vfat` mounted.) Never really bothered to actually use `efibootmgr`, as reinstalling is easier to me.

Comment: (1) Did you restore BIOS default settings? (2) Try in UEFI mode to boot while pressing repeatedly F2 and select the disk check option (if your BIOS has it). Sometimes pressing Esc is required before F2 becomes available. (3) Do hard reset: Turn off, disconnect all connected devices, remove the power cord, take out the battery, press Power button and hold for at least 15 seconds, put the battery back in and connect the AC adapter, finally turn the laptop on.

Comment: I never solved the problem, our technician said that the same also happened to other Debian users, apparently it was a firmware bug. I've finished booting everyday, for months, by selecting "Boot From File" and following the annoying procedure. I've returned the computer to my employer, probably had windows reinstalled. Sorry for not being of more help.

Comment: Does this mean that post & bounty are now abandoned?

Comment: @harrymc: Bounty was set by O__, not me.

Comment: Your part seems then to be terminated. In this case, we are waiting for an answer from @0__ .

Comment: I will look into efibootmgr. For now, it's too risky to do anything. I made backups, and for the time being I will use the select-file work around and avoid rebooting as much as possible. At some point, computer will be returned to employer, so...

Comment: Understood. Post & bounty are abandoned.